# What is (alpha, xn) reaction?

Tags: nuclear-physics

Is (alpha, xn) a reaction where an alpha reacts with a nucleus and multiple neutrons are released? Or does x stand for X-ray? It seems more likely but shouldn't it be gamma ray instead? Are gamma rays and X-rays considered the same?

Comment: can you give an example or where you came across the notation?

Comment: More detail please. That looks like an incident alpha with some number of neutrons departing. So, an (alpha,2n) reaction has 2 leaving. A neutron and a hammer would be (alpha,gn). Lots of examples at your closest ENDF mirror.